# Where is the Invalid Content in Servlet Mapping

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee

Getting the following erorr for invalid url pattern. Trying to follow this tutorial from Telusko exactly. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wty6OROO__8&list=PLsyeobzWxl7pUPF2xjjJiG4BKC9x_GY46&index=6

The action attribute in my form is set to "add" and I've tried with and without the forward slash without success. Please help. Thank you.

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'servlet-mapping'. One of '{"http://
 xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee":url-pattern}' is expected.
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>abc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.centeno.AddServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>abc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-mapping>/add</servlet-mapping>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **url-pattern**, not **servlet-mapping** inside tag **servlet-mapping**

```
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name></servlet-name>
        <url-pattern></url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```